# webdriverIO - Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

While running tests in WebdriverIO the chrome browser crashes with launch with following error:

```
 Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook
Spec file(s): tests/web/src/specs/basic.spec.ts
Error: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

I faced similar issue earlier, which was due to a circular import. This time the circular import isn't the issue.

I am not sure why this error is being raised. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you add code from the spec file, I suspect the problem is in there somewhere